# Reference to another database as a prefix

Tags: 7, users, configuration

I have a problem referencing another database as a prefix in my `settings.php` file.I have a master-site[`mysite.local`] and a slave [`sub.local`].Both of them are having separate database.I need to check the `users table` of the `master-site` as well as the `users table of the slave site` ,when a user tries to authenticate to the slave which is `sub.local`.I tried adding the following in the settings.php file of the slave

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'sub_drupal', //Database for the slave site
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => array(
                'default'   => 'sub_drupal.',
                'users'     => 'study.', //parent database
                'sessions'  => 'study.',
                'role'      => 'study.',
                'authmap'   => 'study.',
                'users_roles'   => 'study.',
            ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

But now it authenticates users only on the parent database.Is it not possible to authenticate users present in the slave database `sub_drupal` and also in the parent database `study`.Hope someone could help me with this.Thanks

Comment: Prefixes are for situations when you have shared database. Of course you will have problem using them to access another DB, as this is simply not what they are for, and thus it's impossible. That's pretty much all to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the format wrong for two databases you need something like this:

```
$databases = array(
  'default' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'database' => 'd7',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'db2' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'database' => 'd7_parent',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can then use `db_set_active('db2');` to change the connection and begin querying the second database.